# Yii2 динамические представления

Tags: yii2

Есть два модуля - items(товары) и images(изображения). Если модуль images активен, то при добавлении/редактировании товара, выводить поле для загрузки изображений(с модуля images), если модуль images не активен или удален, то выводить просто форму добавления/редактировании товара без поля для загрузки изображений. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, как такое можно организовать ?

Comment: `if (Yii::$app->hasModule('images')){ }`

Comment: Не, так не интересно. Хочу больше динамики/гибкости.

Comment: Допустим на уровне кода можно попытаться разрулить с помощью событий, а вот в представлениях как не пойму.

Comment: Пихать логику в представление. Ну такое себе....

Можете в контроллере проверять подключен ли модуль и через **renderPartial** рендерить вьюху из images и передавать результат в виде переменной в вьюху items

Comment: А кто говорит про логику в представлениях ? Я просто не знаю где можно почитать о подобном, вот к примеру есть тот же модуль items и модуль seo, вот если модуль seo активен/установлен, в форму редактирования товара автоматом добавлять сео поля, с модуля seo, сохранили товар, сохранили seo. Вот на уровне абстракции вроде понятно, а как начинаю что-то писать в этом направлении, возникает сразу куча вопросов. Ведь в идеале эти два модуля вообще ничего не должны знать друг о друге.

Comment: Тогда логично создавать промежуточный слой, который будет содержать логику подключения и использования остальных модулей. И будет вам счастье с Dependency Injection. Можете оформить свой функционал в виде Behaviours. А в композитной форме просто подключать их. Посмотрите как сделана Captcha в Yii2